# aligning 2 potentiometer signals

Tags: signal-analysis

I apologize if this is the wrong place to post this question.

I have 2 potentiometer that are connected to a shaft.
1st pot. is connected straight to the shaft.
2nd pot. is connected through a gear set [5:1].

When the shaft do a full circle 360°, the 1st pot. Make a full circle and the 2nd pot. Make 5 circles.

Both potentiometers are the same type with same spec, and output 2 channels (cos and sin).

I want to align both pot signal wave to each other to compare them point by point, and use them in other measurements. For example change the 2nd pot waves from 5 rotation waves to 1 rotation wave like the 1st pot.

I uploaded the excel file on box.com with all info and graphs. Please see it and guide me to a way to align the wave if there is a way.
https://tdu.box.com/s/hv8p8yvmwv5ioaw7wi4qie566aw1bg0f

Thank you in advance.

edit : updated the questions to find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your potentiometers actually already output quadrature signals (your cosine and sine), things are very much alike what you do in communications technology:

Interpret the cosine as real, the sine as imaginary part of a complex signal; then things become pretty straightforward.

So, let's call the cosine signal of the ungeared potentiometer $i_1(t)$, the sine $q_1(t)$. Then you can call the complex rotary signal from your first potentiometer $r(t)={i_1(t)+j\cdot q_1(t)}$, where $j$ is the imaginary unit. The cool thing about $r$ is that it always has the same amplitude 1, so you can do a lot of math on that that wouldn't be sensible on its components.

Specifically, it can also be written at $r(t)=a(t)\cdot e^{j2\varphi t}$, and that $\varphi$ is the current phase of the potentiometer!

So, sensible processing route:

1. Take the i and q signals of the potentiometer,
2. Think of them as parts of a complex signal (that's not requiring to calculate anything)
3. Quite likely: do a bit of low-pass filtering on both, because even the best potentiometers "ring" a lot.
4. Convert that number from the real + imaginary form to polar form, i.e., calculate that $\varphi$ (that takes an arcus tangens)

Now you have an instantaneous phase for every instant. Do the same for the other potentiometer. You will see that the phase value of the geared potentiometer grows five times as fast. You can then either divide it by five to be able to compare it to the ungeared, or you could multiply the phase of the ungeared one by five.

You don't really tell us what you want to do by "aligning" these two signals; chances are this is for some kind of machine control, in which case it would be wise to think about cleaning up your observations, e.g. by driving two PLLs with them, and just work with the error signals and frequencies from the PLLs. But what your actual use case is, I can only speculate.

One thing is relatively certain: excel won't be the tool of choice here. Get your data into an easy to use programming language of your choice - most people these days get along fine with Python - and do the bit of math there.

Answer (score 0):

@mmmm thank you for your helpful feedback.

I actully tried the euler formula before but I guess there is something wrong with my proceess.

from the equation you mentioned above.
r(t)=a(t)⋅e^j2φt

sorting this to,
φ = arctan(Pot. SIN signal (t) / Pot. COS signal (t))

in excle it goes like this,
φ = ATAN2(Pot. SIN signal/ Pot. COS signal)

I tried to divid or multiply the results with 5. but its only change the result amplitude. can you guide me to what i got wrong.

https://tdu.box.com/s/m8p679lphxubc82zr7vh9s48grdybq0i

thanks again for taking the time to help.

Comment: You may edit the original question directly instead of posting an answer to add some information.